# How can I apply outisde borders to a table of angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying this way but it didn't work

The template is:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceListadoEstados" class="mat-table-riesgo-generico">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcion_estado">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPCION </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
          {{data.descripcion}}
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="clase_estado">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CLASE DE ESTADO </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data"> {{data.idClaseEstado.descripcion}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

The css that I apply to the table is

```
table.mat-table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.mat-table-generico {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black !important;
    border-radius: 8px !important;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I apply the class `mat-table-generico` directly to the table tag

Comment: Please provide part of the template you're using.

Comment: Ready there update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that you're *hiding* the border due to the `overflow: hidden` & `border-collapse: collapse` combination

Have a look to my example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1n34j